# Is it ok to to plug your laptop charger in 16 A socket?

Tags: charger

I have an Asus (core i5) laptop. Is it ok to charge my laptop by plugging into a 16 Ampere socket which is normally used for ACs or refrigerator.

Comment: Voltage is the issue, not Amperes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is okay.  Your laptop will only pull as much power (Amps) as it needs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34746/8159) on the Electrical Engineering SE explains better:

> **Current Rating**
>
> Current is a bit different. A constant-voltage supply doesn't determine the current: the load, which in this case is the device, does. If Johnny wants to eat two apples, he's only going to eat two whether you put 2, 3, 5, or 20 apples on the table. A device that wants 2 A of current works the same way. It will draw 2 A whether the power supply can only provide the 2 A, or whether it could have supplied 3, 5, or 20 A. The current rating of a supply is what it can deliver, not what it will always force thru the load somehow. In that sense, unlike with voltage, the current rating of a power supply must be at least what the device wants but there is no harm in it being higher. A 9 volt 5 amp supply is a superset of a 9 volt 2 amp supply, for example.

Your charger will draw only the current it needs from the power line.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the voltage in the main line is within the range mentioned on the laptop adapter, I guess it should be fine.
I have used my laptop, on pure AC, on 110V, 220V and 15A main lines. And here I am posting this answer. So I guess that should not be an issue.
But I do suggest you use a surge suppressor, at all times, no matter what the voltage.